# Python enable logging for executable during run time

Tags: python, logging, exe, pyinstaller

I've created a python module with logging library displaying information. Example of logging output would be...

```
2016-09-28 02:54:39,089 - INFO - dataServer - Listening for incoming connections...
2016-09-28 02:54:41,089 - INFO - dataServer - Listening for incoming connections...
```

I've used pyinstaller to generate an executable from the python module. I was wondering if there was a way to enable the logging to display on command prompt when the executable is executed from the command prompt. I know I log to a file but I want to be able to see the logging information in real time.

Answer (score 1):

You must have added a *FileHandler* to output the content to a file. Similarly to output the content to console add *StreamHandler* in this way **sh = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)** and add this handler to logger by **logger.addHandler(sh)**

Hope this helps, cheers.